# Two Type fields in serialised string, when using using EXTERNAL_PROPERTY with @JsonTypeName

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization

I have a class Animal

```
public class Animal {
  String type;   // Can be dog, cat, elephant
  String name;
  @JsonTypeInfo(
      use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, visible = true)
  AnimalDetails animalDetails;
}
```

I have an `AnimalDetails` abstract class which is deserialised based on an external property `type`.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, visible = true)
public abstract class AnimalDetails {
}
```

And I have a class `DogDetails` which is a subclass of class `AnimalDetails`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeName("dog")
public class DogDetails extends AnimalDetails{
  String type;

  @Builder
  public DogDetails(String type){
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```

The DogDetails also contains a field `type` and I have used `@JsonTypeName` annotation to say that deserialize into a DogDetails when the external `type` is "dog".

When I am trying to serialize the `DogDetails` class then I get two `type` fields.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.harness.ng.remote.NGObjectMapperHelper;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
class Scratch {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DogDetails dog = DogDetails.builder().type("GermanShepherd").build();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    NGObjectMapperHelper.configureNGObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    String jsonValue = "";
    try {
      jsonValue = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dog);
    }catch(Exception ex){
     logger.info("Encountered exception ", ex);
    }
    logger.info(jsonValue);
  }
}
```

Output: `{"type":"dog","type":"GermanShepherd"}`

ExpectedOutupt:  `{"type":"GermanShepherd"}`

I was expecting a single type, How I can solve this issue?

**Jackson version**: 2.7.9

The example(`DogDetails` and `AnimalDetails`) is a representation of the problem I am solving. The best solution for this problem could have been changing the variable name(type), but this schema is decided by our product team and I cannot change this schema.

Comment: How will you deserialize your expected output back into Java objects again? The field name is conflicting. I think you should choose another field name, e.g. "animalType" insead of "type".

Comment: Yes changing the field name will solve this problem, but I cannot change the field name in this case. I have added `JsonTyneName` for the external property, and I think the deserialization with the expected output should work as the class contains the field `type` and it can ignore the above annotation.

Comment: I created a bug for the same https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2844#issuecomment-687920524. The issue might be fixed in some release. There was also an issue in my code `include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY` should only be used over the field and not on the class. This is written in the documentation of the property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add `@JsonIgnoreType` to your subclasses to solve this problem:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeName("dog")
@JsonIgnoreType
public class Dog extends AnimalDetails{
    String type;

    @Builder
    public Dog(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Felix, thanks for the answer. `JsonIgnoreType` didn't  solve the problem. I read that adding it on class will ignore the complete class during deserialization and serialization. But we don't want to ignore the `Dog` class while serialization/deserialization.